# Accessing local repo through jump box with SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

I have an appliance that has an apt-get repo installed on it. Normally I use the following command to make it so I can `apt-get` to it from a remote server.

```
ssh user@IPofRemoteServer -R8880:127.0.0.1:8880
```

However, this requires the local repo appliance to have a connection to the remote server.

I need to do the following:

```
local repo ---> jumpbox ---> remote server
```

So I can run `apt-get update` successfully from the local repo.

I've tried the following to do this with no success:

```
ssh -A -t user@jumpbox -R8880:127.0.0.1:80 ssh -A -t user@remoteServer -R8880:127.0.0.1:80
```

This, however, does not work and upon research, I think this is due to port 8880 just going to 80 on the jumpbox and not actually translating it to forward to the local repo.

I've tried variations without success and I need to do this to update that remote server.

Comment: How is the apt repository configured on the RemoteServer? To which port does it try to connect to? Which port does the local repo listen on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it sufficient to :

```
ssh -A -t user@jumpbox -R8880:remoteServer:80
```

I understand that remote servers port is accessible from jump host?

**EDIT:**
Now, I understand that you have some local repository that you want to show on remote host and use it.

Well, normally I use it like this:
In ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host TargetServer
    Hostname remoteServer
    ProxyJump jumpbox
```

And now you can simply make a ssh connection to your remote server:

```
ssh TargetServer -R8880:localhost:80
```

You are now logged in to your target server. You can verify if tunel is open:

```
netstat -lapn | grep 8880
```

And of course you should be able to make a yum update there.

**EDIT2:**
If you want to use it on the command line without config file use **-J** switch:

```
-J [user@] host [:port]
   Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection to the jump host and then establishing a
   TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.  Multiple jump hops may  be  specified  sepa‐
   rated by comma characters.  This is a shortcut to specify a ProxyJump configuration directive.
```

Comment: No, I need to get from the Local Repo -- through another appliance -- to the appliance I want to apt-get update on.

Comment: Your suggestion just gets me to the jumpbox. I could apt-get update on that jumpbox and it would work, but not on the next server I need to jump to.

Comment: @Kirs Kringle, I updated an answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood your question correctly because you say you want to "apt-get (...) from a remote server" and also "run apt-get update (...) from the local repo".

Here I suppose local is hosting the repo, and remote wants to connect to it.

Either two commands like this:

```
local$   ssh -R 54321:localhost:8880 user@jumpbox
jumpbox$ ssh -R 8880:localhost:54321 user@remote
remote$  apt-get ...
```

Either just:

```
local$  ssh -tAR 54321:localhost:8880 user@jumpbox ssh -R 8880:localhost:54321 user@remote
remote$ apt-get ...
```

For the last one, you need a ssh-agent on local, or you need to be connected to it with `ssh -A` from a machine having an agent.

Of course, your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file on remote would need to have a reference to localhost:8880.

Answer (score 0):

I found this command useful:

```
ssh -L LOCAL_PORT:WEBSERVER:REMOTE_PORT -J jumpuser@JUMPHOST remoteuser@REMOTEHOST
```

Reference: https://pillpall.github.io/linux/2018/02/06/sshscp_jumphost.html